# BLE connection with iOS device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino

My requirement is to connect bluetooth module that has connected in to sensors and  through iOS app and then read sensor data

for this i have used following devices and technologies

1)bluetooth module - HM-10 (BLE Module)
2)iPhone 6
3)arduino  code explained in here  - http://ladvien.github.io/robots/connect-an-arduino-to-iphone/
sensors  - force sensors

Things are smoothly occurring as i expected  can connect and recieve data through bluetooth connection

i have used 7 6 sensors and this is the message format i recieve 
 a:b:c:d:e:f

a = 3 digit number

but if this format size is more than 20 chracters stream will break it and send,
so i  made a small research and it seems BLE Gatt default size is 20 bytes

**so my first question is , is this configurable ? can i revieve more than 20 bytes**

and another thing i have read with apple doc and it says we can send/receive multiple sets of data within in a single connection interval

how can i adjust this configuration ?? coz normally device will take 60ms break before read next set of data

source  -: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/30/ios-core-bluetooth-read-requests/

any explanations for this ?????

Comment: recent for down vote this has been clearly explained ????

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you can not, as far as I know, in any way alter the BLE packet size. Event if you could then that would have to be configured on the peripheral rather than on the central. I know that on BT 4.2 they have added some packet length extension stuff, but I have not looked at it..

Having said all this, I don't see the reason for trying to extend the packet size. If you can't fit the data you need in one packet then you can just split up the data in several packets. You can fit multiple packets within the same connection interval if you are using write commands, but the drawback with that is that they are not ack'ed at application level. Although they are still ack'ed at "BLE level". Write commands correspond to CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse on iOS.

I don't know if this is helpful..